# How to solve colorbox node error "no url found on element"

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website and on one of the pages: http://xenofilia.thedrupalchecklist.com/thevilla/1

I get a strange error: "no url found on element". When I scan the course code I think it is from [colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module, but I'm not sure as I do not know how to debug.

No errors are displayed in the Drupal watchdog en when i click on the images all 14 images are just displayed normally with colorbox node.

How to solve this error?

Comment: where is the error being presented?

Comment: I a popup box the moment you load the page. I you click the link in the question it will appear.